# Subtitles when Video Player is non fullscreen (Roku - Brightscript)

Tags: roku, brightscript

We're experiencing an issue where closed captions/subtitles disappear when the player is not fullscreen:

-When the player is fullscreen (1920px wide) the captions show just fine

-As soon as we change the size of the player, even if it's 1919px wide, the captions suddenly disappear.

-We have tried to play with fields such as setting globalCaptionMode to "On" or suppressCaptions to false, or even changing the captionStyle, the subtitleTracks, but nothing works.

Is there anything else we could try, or is this something that just isn't supported by the native  player ?

Answer (score 1):

With native player, closed captioning works only when video node is playing full screen.